# Save global attribute value when new session starts

Tags: odata, abap, sap-fiori

I have two fields in SAP Fiori App: `Template_ID` and `Offer_ID`.

I want to choose value in `Offer_ID` depending on `Template_ID` field value.

For solving this problem I've tried to do this steps:

When the user click on `Template_ID` field in Back-End runs the method:

`CL_CUAN_CAMPAIGN_DPC->contentset_get_entityset()`.

This method has returning paramater `et_result`. In `et_result` I have the necessary field `temp_id`.

For saving `temp_id` value I created a global attribute in class `ZCL_CUAN_CLASS`.

```
ZCL_CUAN_CLASS=>GV_CONTENT = VALUE #( et_result[ 1 ]-temp_ID OPTIONAL ).
```

I'll use this global attribute as an `input` parameter for my second method:

`CL_CUAN_CAMPAIGN_DPC->GET_OFFER_BY_TEMPLATE()`.

This method returns to me the internal table with the `offer_id`, which belongs to my choosen `temp_id`.

But when the user click on `Offer_ID` field on Web UI, in debugging I see that my global attribute is blank.

May be it's because of session or something else, but it's blank.

[image]

Comment: Please add some more context: What exactly do you mean by "session"? User logs out and in again? Can you share some code that shows how and where exactly you declare `gv_temp_id`? `this.gv_temp_id = ...`? `this.getController().gv_temp_id = ...`? `window.gv_temp_id` or the equivalent `gv_temp_id = '1234';`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Florian for your answer. 
I'll try to add some more information about my problem. I'll edit my Question.

Comment: I'm a beginner but it looks like Fiori and OData services are stateless, so it means that you must send all required data at each request. Why is it a problem in your case?

Comment: I'm new in Fiori and OData as you and it's to diffiсult for me to understand it. I don't have any idea, how to save my necessary value and how can I do all this thing on Back-End, because in Front-End I can't chage anything.

Comment: When the user clicks on `Offer_ID` field, why can't you send the value of the `Template_ID` field? (i.e. that will make it a stateless application, you transfer all required fields)

Comment: I got your logic, but I can't understand how to do that. I mean, how can I send it and where I should do it. I'm absolutely new in this way.

Answer (score 1):

[OData is a **stateless** protocol](https://sapcodes.com/2017/12/27/stateless-vs-stateful-protocol/), meaning the server responds your query, then forgets you were ever there. By definition, this does not allow you to transport main memory content from one request to the next.

User interfaces on the other hand usually require state. It can be gained through one of the following options:

#### Stateful user interface

As Haojie points out, one solution is to store the data that was selected in the user interface and submit it as a filter criterion back to the server with the next request. Having a stateful user interface is the standard solution for stateless server apps.

#### Stateful persistence

Another option is to store the data permanently in the server's database, in ABAP preferredly in a business object. This object has a unique identifier, probably a GUID, that you can reference in your requests to identify the process you are working on.

#### Draft persistence

If not all information is available in one step, such as in a multi-step wizard, should not become "active" right away, or you want to be able to switch devices while working on a multi-step process, drafts are an option. Drafts are regular business objects, with the one specialty that they remain inert until the user triggers a final activation step.

#### Soft state

For performance optimizations, you can have a look at [SAP Gateway's soft state mode](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw751abap/7.51.0/en-US/25/a27ab5fb614b538bc44228fcc9b027/content.htm?no_cache=true), which allows you to buffer some data to be able to respond to related requests more quickly. This is generally discouraged though, as it contradicts the stateless paradigm of OData.

#### Stateful protocol

In some cases, stateless protocols like OData are not the right way to go. For example, banking apps still prefer to pertain state to avoid that users remain logged in infinitely, and thus becoming vulnerable to attacks like CSRF. If this is the case for you, you should have a look at ABAP WebDynpro for your user interface. Generally, stateful server protocols are considered inferior because they bind lots of server resources for long times and thus cannot handle larger user numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Florian for details answer. It was very helpfull information for me. 
Florian if I want to use "Stateful user interface" what should I do for correct applying?
May be can show me any example or explaint to me the steps?

Comment: "Stateful user interface" means that the JavaScript code of your Fiori App stores data in the main memory. This can be simple local variables that are passed around. Many use [JsonModels](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/3677a36d63c6a6160a6b15e3a5d3ea6e7e3eaf48/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel.js) to store data because it's content can be _bound_ to controls. Others [attach data to controls](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/91/f0c3ee6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/frameset.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately I have access only to ABAP code and can't change any java script. What do you think, is there any another way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

When ther user click on OfferId field, it will start a **NEW** session and of course what you store as `GV_CONTENT` in class `ZCL_CUAN_CLASS` is lost.

What you should do is that for the second request you should send to backend with filter `Template_ID` so in your  `CL_CUAN_CAMPAIGN_DPC->GET_OFFER_BY_TEMPLATE()` method, you can further process the result by `Template_ID`.

Or [SET/GET Parameter.](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenmemory.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Haojie. Can you explain to me how can I do it? And is it possible to do that only with Back-End instrumental? I'm new in SAP Fiori and can't understand how can I fix this problem!

Comment: you need to add a $filter to the http request when you request GET_ENTITY_SET in frontend.

Comment: It's the only way to solve my problem? Is it possible only in frontend?

Comment: from my experience, yes. you have to send it from frontend

Comment: Thank you, Haojie for your advice.

Comment: You are welcome. because of two round trips , it cannot be solved in backend unless you persist it which is even worse solution.

Comment: What about this idea:
1. Export iTab with necessary data into abap memory.
2. Import this data from memory in  necessary method.

What do you think does it work?

Comment: No. ABAP memory is not cross session. you can use GET/SET parameter though but it is not a nice solution.

Comment: Yep,  Haojie. I'm trying to use GET/SET parameter , but it's not work. May be I'm wrong in logic or in syntax. 

1. I created in TPARA the new value Z_CONTENT_ID.

2. DATA: lv_mem_cont_id(3) TYPE C.
    lv_mem_cont_id = VALUE #( et_result[ 1 ]-temp_id OPTIONAL ).
    SET PARAMETER ID 'Z_CONTENT_ID' FIELD lv_mem_cont_id.

3. lv_mem_cont_id(3) TYPE C.
    GET PARAMETER ID 'Z_CONTENT_ID' FIELD lv_mem_cont_id.