# Why Export and Import To Memory Id is blank?

Tags: abap

I have two method: `METHOD_A()` and `METHOD_B()`.

In `METHOD_A()` I use another method `METHOD_A_A` which returns me an internal table `et_entityset` with some data.

I want to export `et_entityset` to memory and import it from memory in `METHOD_B()`, but when I import `et_entityset` it's always blank.

My minimal reproducible example:

```
In method METHOD_A():

  DATA et_entityset TYPE some_type.
  lo_camp->METHOD_A_A(
      EXPORTING
        it_order                = SOMETHING
      IMPORTING
        et_entityset            = et_entityset
    ).

  IF et_entityset IS NOT INITIAL.
    EXPORT lt_mem_content FROM et_entityset TO MEMORY ID 'lt_memory_content'.
  ENDIF.
```

```
In METHOD_B():

  DATA lt_mem_content TYPE some_type.
  IMPORT lt_mem_content TO lt_mem_content FROM MEMORY ID 'lt_memory_content'.
  READ TABLE lt_mem_content INTO DATA(ls_mem_content) INDEX 1.
  DATA(lv_content_id) = ls_mem_content-id.
```

Comment: I don't understand how different this question is compared to the one you posted [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58102499/save-global-attribute-value-when-new-session-starts). I think it's better to keep the context of yesterday question, because the right issue is addressed which is about passing data between two different contexts (stateless execution)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sandra. You're right. But I don't know how to do that. Because of this I created a new question.

Comment: I have continued the discussion in your yesterday question. The question is do Fiori and OData services allow stateful sessions (I think no).

Comment: Thank you! Because of this I want to use Export/Import. May be it could help me to solve me problem!

Comment: Are these methods called in the same session?

Comment: You should merge these two questions and delete this, it is more Fiori-specific than simple export/import

Comment: No, I think these method was called in different sessions.

Answer (score 3):

Export to memory / Import to memory is valid  only within a session. 
So assuming you have not made a typo / upper lowercase error with the export and memory commands, then I can only assume you are no longer with the call sequence within a session.
Eg new calls to stateless services, new rfc calls  not reusing a session .

**A cross Workprocess cross session option.**

```
Export ... to SHARED BUFFER
```

HOWEVER, there is NO guarantee the value will be there, as there is an automatic free as required algorithm that will discard entries to make room for new entries.
So if you plan to use this, make sure sufficient memory is allocated to the shared memory buffer.   in AL12 you can monitor the entries.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Phil for your answer. Can you tell me, please, if I would not clear `lt_memory_content` in METHOD_B() doest it works? Can I save me necessary values for another session?

Comment: No, export memory is not a persistent store for across session.  Export to db is. Or better just a table. If you MUST use memory and have it available across workprocesses and across session then EXPORT to SHARED BUFFER can be used

Comment: Thanks a lot, Phil. What do you think about get-set parameter?
1. I created in TPARA the new value Z_CONTENT_ID. 2. DATA: lv_mem_cont_id(3) TYPE C. lv_mem_cont_id = VALUE #( et_result[ 1 ]-temp_id OPTIONAL ). SET PARAMETER ID 'Z_CONTENT_ID' FIELD lv_mem_cont_id. 3. lv_mem_cont_id(3) TYPE C. GET PARAMETER ID 'Z_CONTENT_ID' FIELD lv_mem_cont_id.

Comment: the CUA area used by SET Parameter Id is specific to an application server and not suited to much more than default values. If you have a load balancer and multiple application servers or non stateful applications that result in new user sessions then SPA/GPA isnt of use for passing values around.

Answer (score 1):

The "ABAP memory", which is used by `Export to memory` and `Import to memory`, is accessible only by programs running in the same ["ABAP session"](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenmemory_organization.htm) (explanation of different types of memories and types of sessions in ABAP-based systems).

Two programs may run in the same ABAP session if they call each other, directly or indirectly, via statements like `SUBMIT`, `CALL TRANSACTION`, procedure call, etc.

For example:

- If there are two HTTP calls, that will be two different ABAP sessions. There is one exception for [BSP](https://help.sap.com/viewer/search?q=%22Business+Server+Pages%22&language=en-US&product=SAP_NETWEAVER_750), which is an old SAP technology, there is a "stateful" flag at BSP level which retains and reuses the ABAP sessions.
- If a user logs in once (one user session), and opens a new window (Ctrl+N), all programs executed in that window run in a second "ABAP session", i.e. two programs running in each session cannot communicate via the "ABAP memory".

Example to make two programs exchange some data via the ABAP memory:

```
REPORT zprogram1.
DATA variable TYPE string.
EXPORT memory_name_1 = `A` TO MEMORY ID 'my Z memory 1'.
SUBMIT zprogram2 AND RETURN.
IMPORT memory_name_2 = variable FROM MEMORY ID 'my Z memory 2'.
ASSERT variable = `AB`. " <=== proof that data was transferred via ABAP memory

REPORT zprogram2.
DATA variable TYPE string.
IMPORT memory_name_1 = variable FROM MEMORY ID 'my Z memory 1'.
variable = variable && `B`.
EXPORT memory_name_2 = variable TO MEMORY ID 'my Z memory 2'.
```

PS: an "ABAP session" may be better known as the old name "external session".